# dynamic family tree traverse php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, family-tree

i want to create a family tree website in which members can be added dynamically through backend. I am usin php-mvc,mysql.
I am adding members through backend and I have 4 tables 1. members-details of members and also father,mother ids;
2 partner-to show partner relationships
3 child - to show child relationships
4 sibling - to show sibling relationships

My table structure
Members

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `members_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `members_family` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `members_first_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `members_sur_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_gender` int(10) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-notset,1-male,2-female,3-transgender',
  `members_birth_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_is_living` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_death_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `members_email` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_mobile` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_telephone` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_website` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_blog` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_skype` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_address` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_birth_place` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_death_place` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_profession` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_company` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_interests` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_father` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_mother` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_generation` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_status` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `members_image` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `members_inserttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `members_updatetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`members_id`)
)
```

Partner

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partner` (
  `partner_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `partner_member` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `partner_of_member` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'partner of which member in members_table',
  `partner_relation_status` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-current,2-ex-partner',
  `partner_status` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `partner_inserttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `partner_updatetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`partner_id`)
)
```

child

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `child` (
  `child_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child_member` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `child_of_member` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `child_status` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `child_inserttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `child_updatetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`child_id`)
)
```

sibling

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sibling` (
  `sibling_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sibling_member` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `sibling_of_member` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'sibling of which member in mebers table',
  `sibling_relation` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-younger,2-elder',
  `sibling_status` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `sibling_inserttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `sibling_updatetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sibling_id`)
)
```

I am adding values to this table . Now I need to show this as a tree structure.
 I didnt get any idea from my searchings,
Can anyone help me to traverse data as a family tree .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your table structure is the best solution. You should create 1 table: "Person" and put every person into that table. You could add a "role" field to the "Person" table which indicates the "role" (father, mother, partner, etc..) of that person. More info on hierarchical data: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/.

If you can query the data, then you only have to transform it into a json tree. Take a look at "[jqTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/)" for more info on the json tree structure.